# 3D bar chart in angular 8 application using either d3.js or plotly or three.js

Tags: angular, d3.js, charts, three.js, plotly

Im trying to create a 3D bar chart in angular 8 application. I have tried checking the documentation for d3.js , three.js and plotly chart frameworks but there is no sample for any of them. Can someone post any sample code for my reference? If not these frameworks, any other frameworks will also work. But I need the code in javascript/typescript language only.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can integrate d3 charts to Angular 8

install npm package

```
npm install angular-d3-charts
```

Add following script to your `index.html`

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Add these styles to `style.scss`

```
.tick text {
    font-size: 12px;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #4C5554;
    stroke-width: 1;
}

.x.axis .tick line {
    display: none
}

.domain {
    display: block !important;
    stroke: #4C5554 !important;
    stroke-width: 2 !important;
}
.legend {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    rect {
        stroke-width: 2;
    }
}
```

Add which ever d3 charts component you want to use in `app.module.ts`
To addd bar chart do add `BarChartComponent` in `declarations` like this:

```
import { BarChartComponent } from 'angular-d3-charts'; // this is needed!

@NgModule({
   declarations: [  
   BarChartComponent,
   //...OtherModules 
   ] // along with your other modules
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Use the component in your package:

`app.component.ts`

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  public colors = ["red", "green", "blue"];
  public dataColumns = [1]; // Single Bar Chart
  public barChartData = [
    {
      id: 0,
      label: "label1",
      value1: 10,
      value2: 10,
      value3: 10
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      label: "label2",
      value1: 10,
      value2: 10,
      value3: 10
    }
  ];
}
```

`app.component.html`

```
<angular-d3-bar [id]="test2" [data]="barChartData" [dataColumns]="dataColumns" [colors]="colors" [yAxisTicks]=10 [width]=400
    [height]=200 [transitionDuration]=1000 [transitionDelay]=30 [barWidth]="'16px'"></angular-d3-bar>
```

More information can be found here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-d3-charts#bar-chart

P.S: You may need to install JQuery and d3.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. But these do not give any sample for 3D bar charts